# Customized food for persons based on their profile using Reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, policy-gradients, markov-decision-process, multi-armed-bandits

I am newbie to Reinforcement Learning, this is my idea - Agent(food provider) has to select a food based on the environment(based on the user profile). Here the reward will be given to the agent based on the user's feedback. This is for single person, what if I wanted to make it for multiple persons. I wanted the system to learn on its own and create a policy such that it can identify certain group of people based on their profile and what type of food will be suitable for them.

- Is this possible to implement in Reinforcement learning?
- If so what type of problem is this and what type of solution I can use to solve this.

Comment: I too need an approach like the above question, for my similar problem set

Comment: Please specify the shape and structure of your dataset more clearly.